# for event in pygame.event.get(): pygame.error: video system not initialized when using ssh

Tags: python, joystick

Here is the code that I'm trying to run via ssh into my raspberry pi. It usually works fine when I have a keyboard and monitor connected directly to the raspberry pi, but it doesn't run when I am using ssh.

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()
joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
joystick.init()
#screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
#pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World')

interval = 0.01

# get count of joysticks=1, axes=27, buttons=19 for DualShock 3

joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()
print("joystick_count")
print(joystick_count)
print("--------------")

numaxes = joystick.get_numaxes()
print("numaxes")
print(numaxes)
print("--------------")

numbuttons = joystick.get_numbuttons()
print("numbuttons")
print(numbuttons)
wprint("--------------")

loopQuit = False
while loopQuit == False:

    # test joystick axes
    # outstr = ""
    # for i in range(0,4):
    #       axis = joystick.get_axis(i)
    #       outstr = outstr + str(i) + ":" + str(axis) + "|"
    # print(outstr)

    # test controller buttons
    outstr = ""
    for i in range(0,numbuttons):
        button = joystick.get_button(i)
        outstr = outstr + str(i) + ":" + str(button) + "|"
    print(outstr)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            loopQuit = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                loopQuit = True
```

The error that I am getting is 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "testing_joystick.py", line 47, in 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            pygame.error: video system not initialized

Can anyone help me figure out how to get around this error please?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while since the question has been posted, but I faced the same problem today.

For me the **sudo** command resolved the ssh problem.

```
sudo python code_path.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as described. The problem appears when no X server is available, that's why it works when you have a monitor connected to the Raspberry.

A solution is to run *ssh* with the X forwarding option:

```
    ssh -X pi@raspberry_ip_address
```

Then your program should run as normal:

```
    python your_code.py
```

Hope this helps anybody else.

Comment: Solved my issue (joystick used only as a control input, no screen needed)

Answer (score 0):

Well you have not initialized your window yet. It looks like you may or may not have commented it out: `#screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))`. Many of pygame's events rely on the window. Simply un-comment your screen initialization and it should work fine.

Comment: I found out that it works fine when I have the monitor and keyboard connected directly to the Pi. But doesn't work via ssh. My program doesn't use the screen at all at this point so I commented it out because I still got the same error when it was I commented. Do I need to do anything special if my terminal is via ssh into the Pi?

Comment: What do you mean by _the pi_?

Comment: My apologies, by Pi I meant raspberry Pi

Comment: You have your key-board and monitor connected to a _raspberry pi_? Do  you mean a robot, a computer, or something else?

Comment: A raspberry Pi is a single board computer capable of hdmi video, keyboard and mouse input via usb. It is about the size of a deck of cards. It also has an Ethernet port for network access. It runs a flavor of Debian Linux.

Comment: Could you please post the python TraceBack. It's the error message that your getting.